# Running Apache and Tomcat on guest VM, Tomcat redirects to host

Tags: apache, tomcat, vagrant

I'm trying to deploy my webapp on a Vagrant VM and am having issues with Tomcat redirects and ports.

Here's the configuration:

- Guest OS is Cent OS 6.3 running on Virtualbox.
- Apache 2.4 is installed and running on guest with host port 4000
  being forwarded to guest port 80.
- Tomcat 7 is installed and running on guest with host port 4040 being
  forwarded to guest port 8000 (for JPDA debugger).
- mod_jk is installed to forward requests from Apache to Tomcat.

For the most part, it works. I have one webapp deployed at /mywebapp, which I can access by entering http://localhost:4000/mywebapp into my **host** browser. The problem occurs when the mywebapp application does a credentials check, and issues a redirect if there is no logged in user.

What happens at this point is that my **host** browser URL is changed to **https://localhost**/mywebapp/login.jsp instead of **https://localhost:4000**/mywebapp/login.jsp, which causes me to get an error since I don't have Apache running on my host machine.

I know that mod_jk is working, because I can debug the mywebapp application and follow it to the point where the forward actually happens, so I know that the request is successfully being forwarded **to** Tomcat. Because of this I believe the problem lies with Tomcat and not Apache.

Here is my server.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>
    <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

    <GlobalNamingResources>
        <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
    </GlobalNamingResources>

    <Service name="Catalina">

        <Connector 
            connectionTimeout="20000" 
            port="8080" 
            protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
            redirectPort="8443" />

        <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
        <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>

        <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">

                <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
            </Realm>

            <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">

                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>

            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

If there are any other config files I need to share please let me know.

If I ssh into the guest VM manually and run

```
wget localhost/mywebapp
```

it returns the page as expected. I'm not sure what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS and HTTP run on different ports (443 and 80 respectively, by default), so https://localhost:4000 doesn't really make sense, since HTTP is already using that port.

You need to either:

1. forward the HTTPS port also (probably, this will be messy because forwarding ports under 1000 can only be done by privileged users); or
2. instead of using port forwarding, configure the VM with a [private network](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html) and use the assigned IP address, rather than `localhost` as you are currently.

Option 2 would be my recommendation.

Comment: I thought of that too and tried that, and the redirect would take me from 192.168.0.xx/mywebapp to localhost/mywebapp/login.jsp. HOWEVER! When I manually put the https:// at the beginning, the redirect worked as expected. I'm not sure why or how but it works and I'm happy